Screenline motorized blinds stuck
I have some Screenline motorised blinds. I think this model, with this motor.
One of the blinds will go all the way down, but on the way up stops in the position shown. All of the other blinds work fine. They are installed in two separate places. The broken one is isolated, and only a window, with no connection to a door.
The working ones are part of a three part folding door.
Things I've tried:

Cleaning the contact points in the door.
Individually raising and lowering the blinds.
Raising and lowering the blinds together.
Using the remote and/ or motorised box.
Waiting for warmer weather in case the glass had shrunk.
Shaking the glass as the blind raises in case it's stuck.

Any help welcome!

